# c# multiple expression parameteres

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to create a method signature that takes multiple properties of various type using

I would call it something like this:

```
AllPropertiesExcept(() => Property1, () => Property2)
```

This method almost work, except that the type of the properties have to be the same. I'm only going to use the property name, but want to use lambda expression to enable easy refactoring.

```
public static string MyMethod<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[] propertyExpression)
```

Comment: I don't understand the last bit of code in your question. Is that what you've tried and doesn't work? Is it just pseudo-code?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of using lambdas here.  Couldn't you just use params object[] to accept any values?  If you only want the names, you could accept only strings.

Comment: recursive: the point is that this way, the access is strongly typed. Whereas with strings, they are hardcoded, not caught by refactoring algorithms and not compiler checked, producing runtime exceptions instead of compiler errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `AllPropertiesExcept(params Expression<Func<object>>[] properties)`, you can still get the property names out of it, but it doesn't matter what type the property is.

Edit: However, I would tend to use it the other way round - instead of excluding properties I don't want to see, I would include properties I want to see. The reason is simple - to make your way work, you still need reflection - with my way, you could easily use the `Func` you get to get the actual data directly.

Edit 2 (getting the property name out of an expression):

```
Expression<Func<object>> obj = something; // you get this in your method

((obj.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member.Name
```

I can really advise you to use LinqPad for such things, you can easily drill down objects via `Dump()`, which displays the objects very user friendly. Just recreate a small example and experiment.

Comment: If I have many properties, it's easier to add the ones I don't want. But how can you get the propertyname without the type. I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Does the method `AllPropertiesExcept()` return anything? Otherwise you could make a fluent interface (using method chaining):

```
AllPropertiesExcept(() => Property1)
    .And(() => Property2)
    .And(() => Property3);
```

Even if the `AllPropertiesExcept()` method returns something, you can defer the execution until you invoke a method at the end of the method chain:

```
var foo = AllPropertiesExcept(() => Property1)
    .And(() => Property2)
    .And(() => Property3)
    .DoSomeThing();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to understand the ModelMetadata class documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx

This class is used in ASP.NET MVC in situations like Html.LabelFor(x -> x.Name)
An expression is passed to the ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression Method documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393.aspx

After understanding how it is used in MVC, you could create your own code with some informed knowledge of how it was applied elsewhere.